# Got hit by an UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: android

I have the following code:

```
    private static ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private static List<Chapter> chapters;

    public void update(Book book) {
        adapter.clear();
        if (chapters != null) {
            chapters.clear();
        }
        chapters = DataBaseConnector.getChaptersFromBook(book.getID());
        for (Chapter chapter : chapters) {
            adapter.add(chapter.getTitle());
        }
        header.setText(book.getAbbreviation());
        subHeader.setText(book.getName() + " (" + book.getNumber() + ")");
        subHeader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

If I call the method `update(Book book)` and the variable `chapters` is not `null`, I get hit by an `UnsupportedOperationException` in the line `chapters.clear()`. Any hints how to solve the problem?

Comment: I imagine that you could get away with not having to 'clear' your List, as you are just reassigning it on the very next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have to look at the API documentation, but presumably the `DataBaseConnector.getChaptersFromBook(book.getID())` call is returning an Immutable list, so you can't modify it. It seems you will have to make a local copy.

Comment: How can I check if the method returns an immutable list? I wrote this method by myself.

Comment: What concrete type are you using to create this list?

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild java.util.List

Comment: When you use the 'new' operator, what type is it actually instantiating?

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild Ah ok I see, the list is instantiate using Arrays.asList

Comment: You can try debugging right before you do the clear() and check what actual instance type it is.

Comment: Yeah, Arrays.asList() returns an immutable list. See same problem here: http://rockycode.com/blog/arraysaslist-returns-immutable-list/

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html#clear%28%29) (and JavaDocs as well for the [List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#clear%28%29) interface):

"Throws UnsupportedOperationException if removing from this List is not supported."

My guess is the implementation that is being used does not support the clear() method.